# How to get VBA Subroutine to call a function that passes an array to another function within the subroutine

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to get my VBA subroutine to run a function that creates an array and then passes that array to another function which further processes those array items.  I have made an example that is extremely simple and functions exactly like my actual code.  it is as follows:

```
Sub SubRoutine()
    ProcessArray CreateArray
End Sub

Function ProcessArray(Arr() As Variant) As Variant
End Function
    
Function CreateArray() As Variant
    Dim Array1(1 To 4) As Variant
    CreateArray = Array1
End Function
```

It's just the two functions and the subroutine which calls those two functions. The compiler refuses to compile my code and explains to me that:

Compile error:

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

To which I can only say that everything is the same data type and the argument passed is indeed an array. Just in case you were wondering, yes I have tried with an array that has had data allocated to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:
`Function ProcessArray(Arr() As Variant) As Variant`

to this:
`Function ProcessArray(Arr As Variant) As Variant`

This way your function will now accept a Variant that contains an array, instead of looking for an array of Variants. As you said, a subtle but significant difference.

Comment: Anyt tips for getting a function to return an array of strings without coughing up a type mis-match error (example below):

Function CreateArray() As String()

Dim Array1(1 To 4) As String

CreateArray = Array1

End Function

Comment: @user1902208. that snippet doesn't return an error. You'd just call it like `dim x() as string: x = CreateArray`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what still wasn't answered is why 

1. `MySub(MyArg)`

works just fine, but 

2. `MyOtherSub(MyArg1, MyArg2)`

does not

[This blog entry explains it well.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx)

Essentially, you can pass an argument which would normally be byref as byval:

`Call MySub(Arg1, (Arg2)) 'Arg1 is passed byref, Arg2 is passed byval`

Code #1. works because VBA thinks you are passing one argument byVal so it doesnt count as parentheses being used in a `Sub` call without the `Call` keyword. As mentioned in other answers, no parentheses are allowed in a `Sub` call without the `Call` keyword.

The `Call` keyword requires Params in parentheses. So with the `Call` keyword `Call MySub(MyArg)` would actually pass `MyArg` byRef because the parentheses are used as the enclosure for arguments.

Code #2 does not work because there is no valid way to justify the parentheses in the syntax (it is only allowed with the `Call` keyword.